# Showing the existence of rings which do not satisfy the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm supposed to give a constructive proof of the following claim, but to get some hints on what to do I tried to prove the inverse and see where the proof breaks down. I have the following.

Claim: Define $X * Y = \{ xy \mid x \in X, y \in Y\}$. There is a ring $R$ with ideal $U$ such that $R / U$ is not closed under *.

What I've done:

Observe $S := (a + U) * (b + U) = \{ xy \mid x \in a + U, y \in b + U\}
= \{(a + u_1)(b + u_2) \mid u_1, u_2 \in U\} 
= \{ ab + au_2 + u_1b + u_1u_2 \mid u_1, u_2 \in U\}$
Since $U$ is an ideal, $au_2 + u_1b + u_1u_2 \in U$. Therefore, $(a + U)*(b + U)$ could only possibly equal $ab + U$. Thus if I can find a $u \in U$ not expressible as $au_2 + u_1b + u_1u_2$, then that completes the claim, as it would make $(a + U)*(b + U)$ a strict subset of $ab + U$. But at this point I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being asked to produce an example, not a proof: take $R = \Bbb{Z}$ and $U = 2\Bbb{Z}$. Then $U \in R/U$, but $U*U = 4\Bbb{Z} \not\in R/U$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$, the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Let $ U = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \}$, the set of upper triangular matrices of $R$.

I claim that $R / U$ is not closed under $*$.

You can show this by showing $U * \left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} +U  \right)\notin R/U$.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} +U = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}   \}$

$U * \left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} +U  \right) = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\} \notin U$